# Java : A query about jar files

Tags: java, jar

While Uploading a war file to the server , can you please tell ,
what jar files should be acutually kept inside the server lib ?

Because I see, all the jar files which we keep during eclipse 
Build path will not be present inside the war lib (required for compilation suppourt )

Comment: Difficult to answer in general. What jar files are we talking about, and what server do you plan to deploy to?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question, i am using Tomcat 6.0 version and the jars are specific to my Application only .

Answer (score 1):

Basically depends depends on what your app server provides.  For example, you app server will provide things like the javax.servlet packages, so you shouldn't include the servlet-api jars that you required for compilation.  Some app server will provide the java mail apis, so you shouldn't include those.  Some app servers wont, so you'll the jar files.  Hope this helps.

Edit: if by specific to your app you mean that you wrote them, then you need them in the war.

Comment: so you mean o say all application specific related jars which are present during compilation support , should be also present inside war file lib ??

Comment: How can they be both "compilation support" and application-specific? If those are well known jar files, let us know. If you wrote them yourself, only you will know if they are required at runtime or not. For certain, they will not be present in a stock Tomcat6.

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the Eclipse build path entries should be present, but generally, all of the actual "jar" dependencies should be present. The small list of exceptions will be things provided by the server. (These will mostly be things like database connectors when the connection will be provided by the server as opposed to created by the application. If you're using Tomcat instead of a full app server, you might be creating connections in the app instead of getting them from the server. In that case, you'd need to include any database connector jars.)

Any Library entries (e.g., JRE System Library, Web Container libraries) will need to be available through the server, and not bundled in the WAR.